# Google Sheets Script getLastRow() not returning all values

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have email addresses in first column. When I try to get the last row of this column, the function only returns the first two values. Here is a link to the sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1piGCiWMcUKUWagIJSZ_0SxxuNG3tcEcrx-fKnMDOIlQ/edit?usp=sharing

Here is the script function:

```
function myFunction() {
  var rangeLastRow = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange(2, 1).getLastRow(); 
  var emails = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange(2, 1,rangeLastRow).getValues();
  Logger.log(emails);
}
```

Shouldn't it be returning all of the email addresses in the first column?

It is only returning the first two email addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's working correctly. [`range.getLastRow()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getLastRow()) returns the absolute index of the **last row of the range**.  Your line

```
var rangeLastRow = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange(2, 1).getLastRow();
```

returns the row index of cell A2 that you specified in `getRange(2, 1)`, so your call to `range.getValues()` is getting the values of the range A2:A3. i.e. Your call to `range.getLastRow()` returns 2 because your range is (row 2, col 1), so your call to `range.getValues()` is looking at the range (row 2, col 1, 2 rows)

You want the **last row of data in the sheet**, which you get with [`sheet.getLastRow()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getLastRow()).  In fact, why not do away with `var rangelastRow` altogether? The following give you the result you're after:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var emails = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange(2, 1,ss.getLastRow() - 1).getValues();
  Logger.log(emails);
}
```

Note that you actually want to use `getLastRow() - 1` at set the number of rows in the range because your range starts at row 2, not row 1.

Answer (score 2):

How about this modification?

#### Modification points :

- `getRange(2, 1).getLastRow()` means that it is to retrieve the last row for the range of "a2". So the result is 2.

  - In order to retrieve the last　row of the sheet, please use `SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1').getLastRow()`
  - The 3rd parameter of `getRange(row, column, numRows)` is the `numRows`. When you want to retrieve data of "a2:a6", `numRows` is `rangeLastRow - 1`.

    - By above reason, `getRange(2, 1, 2).getValues()` retrieves only 2 cells.
- `SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1')` can be used by importing a variable.

The modified script which reflected above is as follows.

#### Modified script :

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
var rangeLastRow = sheet.getLastRow(); 
var emails = sheet.getRange(2, 1, rangeLastRow - 1).getValues();
Logger.log(emails);
```

#### References :

- [getRange(row, column, numRows)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow-column-numrows)