# "The coordinates of the range are outside the dimensions of the sheet" error when sorting

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create a script to sort a table on the current active sheet/tab but I am getting an error that I could not identify. I keep getting `The coordinates of the range are outside the dimensions of the sheet.`. My table has data in them from columnA to columnQ. Data in columnA are identification numbers and columnB to columnQ contain formulas. What am I doing wrong with my script?

```
var sortFirst = 7; //index of column to be sorted by; 1 = column A, 2 = column B, etc.
  var sortFirstAsc = true; //Set to false to sort descending

  var sortSecond = 8;
  var sortSecondAsc = true;

  var sortThird = 9;
  var sortThirdAsc = true;

  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var sheetName = activeSheet.getSheetName(); //name of sheet to be sorted
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn());
  range.sort([{column: sortFirst, ascending: sortFirstAsc}, {column: sortSecond, ascending: sortSecondAsc}, {column: sortThird, ascending: sortThirdAsc}]);
```

Comment: if you log `sheet.getLastRow()` and `sheet.getLastColumn()`, what do you get?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's very likely that the error occurs on the line

```
var range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn());
```

It's very likely that the solution is to change it by

```
var range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, sheet.getLastColumn());
```

The above because the range start on row 2 and because it's very likely that sheet has content on its last row.

Related

- [Google Sheets Script getLastRow() not returning all values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47642693/1595451)
- [Need help debugging Google Apps Script code intended to update hundreds of files in Google Drive](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66711145/1595451)

Comment: Hi Ruben, thank you for that, the columns B to Q does have formulas and it looks like adding a `-1` did work but now my problem is although it is sorting the table, it is including the rows with blank non-visible values (Just contained formulas) so the result is the rows with visible values ends up at the bottom of the sheet and the blank ones at the top. How can I make the sorting use the last row of rows with visible values? Or how can I make the line of code above to sort only from row 2 up to the last row of columnA?

Comment: @Jay Please post a new question.

Comment: this answer is a hack, not a solution

Comment: @MC9000 what do you mean? What do you expect as a solution for this question considering the content of the question?

Comment: The content of the question exposes the problem whereby sorting and other Google Sheets functions don't work when the  row count is equal to or greater than the max count. This solution will truncate the last value and doesn't solve the question!

Comment: @MC9000 that appreciation is incorrect (the row count could never be greater than the max row). Perhaps you are missing that the range starts in row 2, not in row 1.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the work around for this bug in Google Sheets:
It simply adds a row to the end of the sheet whenever the lastrow is greater than or equal to maxrows. This is not done automatically from the scripting side (though hundreds of other behind-the-scenes functions are called by Google's system to emulate working on a spreadsheet).

```
let maxRows = mySheet.getMaxRows();
if(mySheet.getLastRow() >= maxRows) {mySheet.insertRowsAfter(maxRows,1);}
```

I hope this helps all those suffering from this problem when Sorting, Deduplicating, etc on Google Sheets.