# Need help debugging Google Apps Script code intended to update hundreds of files in Google Drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-shared-drive

The company I work for just updated its branding, affecting hundreds of Excel and PowerPoint files saved to a Shared Google Drive. There is a team working to update the files. My challenge is finding an efficient way to add the new files and delete the old files in Google Drive.

I created a Google Sheet to capture the current File Id, the new File Id, and the Folder Id, along with the following Google Apps Script code. The code throws the following error.

> Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property getFileById on object DriveApp. 
> BulkUpdate  @ Bulk Update.gs:25

Hoping someone can help me debug? I'm a novice and I've hit a wall.

```js
function BulkUpdate() {
  
  // This constant is added to updated files
  var success = "Success"

  // Define range 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var firstRow = 2; // First row of data to process
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow(); // Last row of data to process

  // Fetch range
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(firstRow, 1, lastRow, 4);

  // Fetch values for each row in range
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var folderId = row[0]; // First column
    var currentFileId = row[1]; // Second column
    var newFileId = row[2]; // Third column
    var confirmation = row[3]; // Fourth column

    // Copy new file to folder and trash current file
    if (confirmation !== success) {
      var currentFile = DriveApp.getFileById(currentFileId);
      var newFile = DriveApp.getFileByID(newFileId);
      var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
      newFile.makeCopy(folder);
      currentFile.setTrashed(true);

      // Update spreadsheet
      sheet.getRange(firstRow + i, 4).setValue(success);
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
  }
  
  // Create a popup window
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Updates Complete");
}
```

Comment: I understand that you fixed the camel case at line 25, what's the error you are getting after that change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all. Turns out I needed to subtract one from `lastRow` in defining 'dataRange'. Below you will find the final code for reference.

```js
function onOpen() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var menuItems = [{name: 'Update Google Drive', functionName: 'bulkUpdate'}];
  sheet.addMenu('Menu', menuItems);
}

function bulkUpdate() {
  
  // This constant is added to updated files
  var success = "Success"

  // Define range 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var firstRow = 2; // First row of data to process
  var firstColumn = 1; // First column of data to process
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow(); // Last row of data to process
  var lastColumn = 6; // Last column of data to process

  // Fetch range
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(firstRow, firstColumn, lastRow - 1, lastColumn);

  // Fetch values for each row in range
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var row = data[i];
    var folderId = row[1]; // Second column
    var currentFileId = row[3]; // Fourth column
    var newFileId = row[4]; // Fifth column
    var confirmation = row[5]; // Sixth column

    // Copy new file to folder and trash current file
    if (confirmation !== success) {
      var currentFile = DriveApp.getFileById(currentFileId);
      var newFile = DriveApp.getFileById(newFileId);
      var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
      newFile.moveTo(folder);
      currentFile.setTrashed(true);

      // Update spreadsheet
      sheet.getRange(firstRow + i, 6).setValue(success);
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      continue;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a typo

```
var currentFile = DriveApp.getFileById(currentFileId);
var newFile = DriveApp.getFileByID(newFileId);
```

`getFileByID` id is all uppercase, I guess it should be `getFileById` according to the API docs. Also, try printing the `currentFileId` and `newFileId`.

Comment: Good catch... fixed the capitalization, but there is still an error. Added `console.log(currentFileId)` and `console.log(newFileId)` and `currentFileId` and `newFileId` appear to be correct. The console logs a 44 character alphanumeric string matching the URL. The error remains the same. Any other thoughts?