# "The coordinates of the range are outside the dimensions of the sheet"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to sort a range that goes from the first cell of the 3rd row (C3) and goes until the last row and the seventh column.

No matter what I try I get the error **"The coordinates of the range are outside the dimensions of the sheet"**

Any idea where I'm going wrong? I've included my code below.

Thanks!

```
function onEdit(event){
  
  Utilities.sleep(900);
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];  
  var range = sheet.getRange(3,1,sheet.getLastRow(),7);
  range.sort (7) 
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `from the first cell of the 3rd row (C3) and goes until the last row and the seventh column` and your script of `var range = sheet.getRange(3,1,sheet.getLastRow(),7);`. In your script, `A3:G` is used. So I cannot understand `from the first cell of the 3rd row (C3)`. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing this line...

`var range = sheet.getRange(3,1,sheet.getLastRow(),7);`

to this...

`var range = sheet.getRange(3,1,sheet.getLastRow()-2,7);`

As your current line reads, you are asking to start on Row 3 and then extract the *entire* number of rows in the sheet. For instance, if your sheet only had 10 rows, you're asking to start at Row 3 and count 10 rows from that point, which is not possible.

You have to discount for the number of rows above your start range (which, in this case, is 2).

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
function onEdit(e){
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  sh.getRange(3,1,sh.getLastRow() - 2,7).sort({column:7,ascending:true})
}
```

or this way:

```
function onEdit(e){
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  sh.getRange("A3:G" + String(sh.getLastRow())).sort({column:7,ascending:true})
}
```

Note: this function runs on all edits of all sheets.  You should consider limiting access to unwanted sheets because not doing so will effect spreadsheet performance.

Really I can't think of any reason for using sleep in an onEdit function.

Comment: I used sleep just to make sure that they can edit the row a little bit before it instantly gets sorted.

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs because your sheet has less rows than the value returned by `sheet.getLastRow()` plus the offset caused by the start row of the range, in this case 2.

One solution not requiring to change your code is to add more rows to the sheet but a most appropriate solution (already mentioned in the previous answers) is to replace `sheet.getLastRow()` by `sheet.getLastRow() - 2`.

Related

- [Google Sheets Script getLastRow() not returning all values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47642693/1595451)
- ["The coordinates of the range are outside the dimensions of the sheet" error when sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49157222/1595451)
- [Need help debugging Google Apps Script code intended to update hundreds of files in Google Drive](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66711145/1595451)